# What is the type of b in this code snippet?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} NodeT;
const NodeT *a,b,c;
```

Is variable b actually a constant struct element?

Comment: No, it is not. It is a `const struct node` **variable**, not a `struct` element and not a constant. `const` does not mean it is _constant_, but tells the compiler you will never change it after initialisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is variable b actually a constant struct element?

Your `b` has type `const NoteT`, which means `const struct node`, as the declaration :

```
const NoteT *a,b,c;
```

is equivalent to :

```
const NoteT *a;
const NoteT b;
const NoteT c;
```

---

In general, if you have a declaration like :

```
type *x, y, z, *w, ... ;
```

the type `type` applies to all variable, but only those who have a `*` in front of them are pointers to that type.

Comment: OP asks for "constant". `const` does not mean "constant"! And `NoteT` is just an alias, so the actual type is `const struct node`

Comment: @Olaf where does that apply to my answer?

Comment: It did before you edited, as you wrote "yes it is". Which was wrong. The rest of my comment still applies.

Comment: Just to add: The `*` like `[]` are different parts of the grammar (part of the type-specifier) than the qualifiers and storage-class-specifiers. Which is the reason `int* p;` is missleading to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

`b` has fully-qualified type `const struct node`. The `const` qualifier applies but the pointer doesn't.

Comment: The type is `const struct node`. `NodeT` is just an alias.

Comment: @Olaf, you're correct again. Precision is important. I'll delete this.

Comment: Actually, I amended instead. The other answer buries this.

Comment: @Olaf, the type is `struct node`,  `const` is a qualifier :)

Comment: @KeineLust `const` is a type-qualifier, which _qualifies_ it as part of the type with respect to the question;-). Let's say I just forgot to write "fully qualified type".

Answer (score 0):

```
const NodeT *a,b,c;
```

Read it backwards and since you are only interested in `b`

```
const NodeT b;
```

`b` is a `const NodeT`

`NodeT` is `struct node`

Hence `b` is a `const struct node`